# How to check if value is greater than another using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using javascript to check if the value entered by the user is greater than the value there. But when I click update it just redirect to another page without giving the error message.

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function onUpdateClick () {
    var initVal = $('#quantity').val();

    $('#quantity').change(function () {
        if ($('#quantityI').val() > initVal)
            console.log('Quantity issued should be less than quantity requested');
        else {

            location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Issue")';
        }
    });
```

View

```
   <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , @readonly="readonly", @id=quantity} })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantityI, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantityI, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id=quantityI } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantityI, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

Model
    [Required]

```
    [Range(0.5,double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must enter an amount greater than Zero")]
    [Display(Name ="Quantity Requested")]        
    public double quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(0.5, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must enter an amount greater than Zero")]
    [Display(Name = "Quantity Issued")]
    public double quantityI { get; set; }
```

Comment: move the line var initVal = $('#quantity').val();
inside of your .change handler and it should work.

Comment: val() are strings

Comment: no that didn't work either

Comment: ok what should I change it to. Is there another I could check if the value is greater?

Comment: hi i resolved issue , please check my updated answser you need to make use of parseInt() function of javascript as you want to compare intergervalue

Comment: Use a conditional validation attribute (for example a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` attribute - or if you want to write your own - [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)) so that you get correct client and server side validation out of the box. (and your use of `location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Issue")';` makes no sense at all)

Comment: you can also upvote answer if you like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found issue with you code , you need to make use of `parseInt()` function when fetching value.

Following is working

```
<input type="Text" id="quantity"  />
<input type="Text" id="quantityI" />

$(function() 
{
   $('#quantity').change(function () 
    {
      var quantityI =  parseInt($('#quantityI').val());
      var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
      alert(quantityI);alert(quantity);
     if( quantityI > quantity)
      {
        alert('Quantity issued should be less than quantity requested');
      }
     else {
        alert('Else called');
       }
    });
 });
```

Working Demo :  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ocgjynt/)

Comment: so i should remove .change(function ()

Comment: @SujaeBrown - you dont need to remove change function ...you need to move change function inside doucment.ready function ..which means when document get loaded event handler get bind to change event of textbox

Answer (score 0):

Your descriptions is missing some steps. Anyway I will try to give some points, hope it will help.
The initial value of the controls is an empty string (as far as I can tell) so comparing them will give a string compare of two empty strings.
Take note that in some versions of FireFox the final control's value is set  after it looses focus, so sometimes the value that you get is the old one at onchage event...

Comment: Ok i understand what you're saying but seeing i'm using id in html then wouldn't the values be stored there? Is there a simpler way

Comment: You are on the right track (cannot be 100% sure).
If the logic is ok, then you should just try to parse to number like: